# show a loading image when user clicks on next button in installer made by using Innosetup script

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I want to show a loading image when user click on next button in installer made using Innosetup deployment script..Is there any way to do this.

Comment: During what setup step/process?

Comment: when running the setup,i have a step where i check for some license key using a inline exe which connects to a license database using a WCF service.If validation is true then installer continues...During this step,when it takes the parameters from the setup program and returns value from validation exe,setup seems to be hanging for a moment...may be some 30 seconds...at this moment i want to show a loading gif/image ,so user has a interactive experience,that is something is going on.

Comment: any answers on above issue???? this is urgent :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a custom wizard page. In this page you can put an image

There are example in inno setup examples directory about creating custom wizard page.
Basically your script section page would look like this

```
[Code]
Var
  MyPage: TWizardPage;

Procedure CreateMyPage;
Var
  MyImageDisplay: TBitmapImage;
  MyImage: TBitmap;
Begin
  MyPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectDir, 'Licence checking', 'The setup will now verify your licence');
  //
  MyImageDisplay := TBitmapImage.Create(MyPage.Surface);
  // set the props... do something with it
  MyImage := TBitmap.Create;
  // set the props, load a file
  MyImageDisplay.Bitmap.Assign(MyImage)
End;

procedure InitializeWizard;
Begin
  CreateMyPage;
End;
```

Comment: Consider that the custom page might be created several times since you can go back to the welcome page. The right approach is to create the custom pages once in the [`InitializeWizard`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) event.